# How to call multiple stages twice in a jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Consider like I have few stages in jenkins pipeline

```
stage ("File Operations") {
   steps{
      sh "OS=android npm run read-device"
   }
}

stage ("File Operations") {
   steps{
      sh "OS=android npm run read-suite"
   }
}

stage ("File Operations") {
   steps{
      sh "OS=android npm run read-device"
   }
}

stage ("File Operations") {
   steps{
      sh "OS=android npm run read-suite"
   }
}
```

This stages I need to call multiple times but with a different value , So is it possible I can call these 4 stages only twice, by passing some parameter, or defining it at some place and calling that ? Please help

Comment: Is this declarative or scripted pipeline syntax?

Comment: scripted pipeline @MattSchuchard

Comment: `['read-device,'read-suite','read-device','read-suite'].each {stage('File Operations'){ sh "OS=android npm run ${it}" }}`